# How to kill a process in MacOS?

Tags: macos

I tried `kill -9 698` but the process did not die.

```
$ ps -ef | grep chromium
  502   698   811   0   0:01.24 ??         0:07.28 /Users/lucius/chromium/src/xcodebuild/Debug/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
  502   854   732   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.00 grep chromium
$ kill -9 698


$ ps -ef | grep chromium
  502   698   811   0   0:01.24 ??         0:07.28 /Users/lucius/chromium/src/xcodebuild/Debug/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
  502   854   732   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.00 grep chromium
```

Comment: Isn't it a good practice to first execute `kill -15 ...` and if that doesn't work then `kill -1 ...` and if that doesn't work then `kill -9 ...` ?

Answer (score 175):

If you're trying to kill -9 it, you have the correct PID, and nothing happens, then you don't have permissions to kill the process.

**Solution:**

```
$ sudo kill -9 PID
```

---

Okay, sure enough Mac OS/X does give an error message for this case:

```
$ kill -9 196
-bash: kill: (196) - Operation not permitted
```

So, if you're not getting an error message, you somehow aren't getting the right PID.

Comment: Could be right but I seem to recall kill giving an error message if the process wasn't owned by the killer.

Comment: God, that's one of those behaviors that is different from UNIX to UNIX.  It's desirable *not* to have that error, because it's a covert channel; on the other hand it's a useful error message.

Comment: Which UNIX gives no error here? I've test BSD, Linux and Solaris and all give some form of the above error (EPERM).

Comment: I don't know, although if I had to guess I'd guess Solaris with trusted extensions (the covert channel issue.)  Also, notice that there are a couple blank lines after the kill.  I wonder why?

Comment: this was the only way to slay the demon on my port, thank you

Answer (score 29):

Some cases you might want to kill all the process running in a specific port. For example, if I am running a node app on 3000 port and I want to kill that and start a new one; then I found this command useful.

Find the process IDs running on TCP port 3000 and kill it

```
kill -9 `lsof -i TCP:3000 | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}'`
```

Comment: exactly what is needed

Answer (score 8):

You can list the process using a port with command `lsof`, for example:

```bash
lsof -i tcp:PORT_NUMBER_HERE
```

Replace the word `PORT_NUMBER_HERE` to the port number that you are using, then the process running on the port will be listed. Then you just have to kill the process ID founded like this:

```bash
kill PID_NUMBER
```

Where `PID_NUMBER` is the process ID running on the port.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the process name you can use:

```
killall Dock
```

(Replacing "Dock" with the process name.) If you don't know the name of the process, you can open Activity Monitor and find it.

Comment: I think it might be a bad idea to actually run that command. I suppose you could fairly easily just restart the dock, but I don't know if there would be any problems with that approach.

Comment: It was just an example of a process, I don't want him to kill his dock. I am assuming `killall` takes a different string compared to kill.

Answer (score 4):

If `kill -9` isn't working, then neither will `killall` (or even `killall -9` which would be more "intense"). Apparently the chromium process is stuck in a non-interruptible system call (i.e., in the kernel, not in userland) -- didn't think MacOSX had any of those left, but I guess there's always one more:-(. If that process has a controlling terminal you can probably background it and kill it while backgrounded; otherwise (or if the intense killing doesn't work even once the process is bakcgrounded) I'm out of ideas and I'm thinking you might have to reboot:-(.

Answer (score 4):

I just now searched for this as I'm in a similar situation, and instead of `kill -9 698` I tried `sudo kill 428` where 428 was the pid of the process I'm trying to kill. It worked cleanly for me, in the absence of the hyphen '-' character. I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes try sudo kill -9 PID - this worked for me (idk why we can't kill it from the user and require elevation)

Answer (score 3):

Given the path to your program, I assume you're currently running this under Xcode, and are probably at a debug breakpoint. Processes cannot be killed in this state because of the underlying implementation of breakpoints.

The first step would be to go to your Xcode process and stop debugging. If for some strange reason you have lost access to Xcode (perhaps Xcode has lost access to its gdb sub-process), then the solution is to kill the gdb process. More generally, the solution here is to kill the parent process. In your case this is PID 811 (the third column).

There is no need to use -9 in this case.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that if `kill -9 PID` doesn't work and you own the process, you can use `kill -s kill PID` which is kind of surprising as the man page says you can `kill -signal_number PID`.

Comment: `kill -s kill 9` helped me

Answer (score 2):

in the spotlight, search for Activity Monitor. You can force fully remove any application from here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced similar issue where the atom editor will not close. Neither was responding. Kill / kill -9 / force exit from Activity Monitor - didn't work. Finally had to restart my mac to close the app.

Answer (score 0):

To terminate a process:

```
kill -s KILL [PID]
```

Where **-s** specifying the *signal name* to be sent to PID

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Force Quit dialogue box by pressing `⌘` + `⌥` + `esc`, or using the Apple Menu (top left corner of the screen) and choosing Force Quit... Select the problem app, and click the Force Quit button.

[image]