# How can I interrupt a python script that is running in the background on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, interrupt

I have got an python script, that is running in the background and that is working with watchdog and os. Is there a way to force quit such a script? I have already tried to press `ctrl + x` or `ctrl + z` as proposed in other discussions, what didn't work for me.

Comment: have you tried `fg` followed by `ctrl+c`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill a process in MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903076/how-to-kill-a-process-in-macos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sent your process to background with an `&` at the end of the command line, you can bring it back to the foreground with `fg`. Once it's back to the foreground, you can kill it with `Ctrl+C`

`test.py`:

```
from time import sleep

n = 0
while True:
    sleep(1)
    n += 1
    print(n)
```

Example output:

```
$ python3 -q test.py &
[1] 82675
$ 1
2
3
4
fg
5
6
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This works from the same shell where you started your script. From another shell, you can find the process ID (PID) with `ps`, and then kill it with `kill -9 <PID>`. BTW, the first output line in the above example tells you the PID (`82675` in this case).

Assuming you have no other process containing the name of your script in the command line, you could even do this (replacing `test.py`):

```
$ kill -9 $(ps | fgrep test.py | fgrep -v fgrep | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will run the command `jobs`
you will see something like this

```sh
[1]  + suspended  python .....
```

You then can run `kill %<job-number>`
And you will see:

```sh
[1]  + 43347 killed     vim python ...
```

Comment: Ok, but when i run the command jobs by typing it into the terminal, I actually get no output: `IMAC221:~ wewar$ jobs                                                                               
IMAC221:~ wewa$ ` Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: this usually mean that you have no background jobs